# What are the compact objects in the homotopy category of diagram spectra?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a discrete index category and $\mathcal{S}$ the category of (e.g.) orthogonal spectra. We consider the homotopy category $\mathrm{Ho}(\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{C,S}))$ of diagram spectra indexed by $\mathcal{C}$.

An object $T$ is as usual called compact if for any small family $(X_i)_{i\in I}$, the natural map
$$\bigoplus [T,X_i] \rightarrow [T, \coprod X_i]$$
is an isomorphism.

A finite object is an object of the form $\Sigma^N\Sigma^{\infty}A$ where $A$ is a finite $\mathcal{C}$-CW-complex, up to isomorphism in the homotopy category. Every finite object is compact.

**Question:** Is every compact object finite?